# Howto load npm modules with files other than js in meteor

Tags: meteor, npm, package, reactjs

I'm trying to package the material-ui react npm module for meteor but always get an error for the jsx tags contained in the jsx files.

```
material-ui/src/js/app-bar.jsx:31
W20141121-19:42:18.097(1)? (STDERR)     if (this.props.title) title = <h1 className="mui- app-bar-title">{this.prop
W20141121-19:42:18.097(1)? (STDERR)                                   ^
W20141121-19:42:18.098(1)? (STDERR) SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
```

The jsx files have to be preprocessed somehow before being collected by meteor. Meteor provides preprocessing of files included in the project by Package.registerBuildPlugin, but how do I do this when I package npm modules? My package.js looks like this

```js
Npm.depends({
  "material-ui": "0.3.0"
})

Package.onUse(function(api) {
  api.versionsFrom('1.0');
  api.use('jhartma:react@0.0.2', ['client','server']);
  api.addFiles('plugin/index.js',['server','client'])
});
```

Comment: Check [material-ui](https://atmospherejs.com/izzilab/material-ui) to use material-ui with Meteor.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a react-meteor npm package to compile your JSX: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-meteor

Comment: You should include the answer in your answer; links should be for supplemental information, not the content of your reply.